# enable / disable based on the null value for p:inputText

Tags: jsf, disabled-input

I want to create a JSF application.   In the application the user will search for the user records from the database and set the values in the form, and then submit the form.
I have a small issue where I need to enable / disable  based on the null value for p:inputText

- If a null value is set for the field from the database, then enable
  the input for the  p:inputText
- If a value is  set for the field from the database, then disable or
  make it read only the p:inputText

This way the user will be able to enter  values if no value is set into the field. 
How this can be implemented?

```
<p:inputText id="firstName"  value="#{javaMB.infoEntity.firstName}"/>
<p:inputText id="lastName"  value="#{javaMB.infoEntity.lastName}"/>
<p:inputText id="age"  value="#{javaMB.infoEntity.age}"/>

this.infoEntity.setFirstName(view.getFirstName());
this.infoEntity.setLastName(view.getLastName());
this.infoEntity.setAge(view.getAge());

        DB 

        Mark   XYZ   45
        Sav    NULL  23
        NULL   Jones 33
```

If we set the second row then p:inputText for first name is disabled,  p:inputText for last name is enabled, p:inputText for age is disabled. 
If we set the third row then p:inputText for first name is enabled, p:inputText for last name is disabled, p:inputText for age is disabled

---

What I have tried

Using a readonly="true" did not work as I need to enter the p:inputText if a null value is set for it.

```
<p:inputText id="lastName"  value="#{javaMB.infoEntity.lastName}"  disabled="{!check}"/>                    
public Boolean check{set;}
```

Let me know if any clarifications are required,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use power of Java EE [EL (Expression Language)](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gjddd.html).

In your case, following declarations will generate **disabled** `p:inputText` if value of *lastName* is **not null**

```
<p:inputText id="lastName" value="#{javaMB.infoEntity.lastName}"  
             disabled=#{not empty javaMB.infoEntity.lastName}/>
```

or

```
<p:inputText id="lastName" value="#{javaMB.infoEntity.lastName}"  
             disabled=#{javaMB.infoEntity.lastName != null}/>
```